# Film where a man fights robots and protects a woman and her baby. A robot rips off his arm and he replaces it with a robot arm

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

This muscular guy who fights lots of robots. Then there's a scene where this robot is hanging from his arm, and cuts it off. The guy, not having an arm, puts on the ripped-off arm of the robot.

There's also a woman with a baby in glass who he's trying to protect.

Comment: hi, there are lots of ways to improve your question and increase a chance of an answer. When did you see it?, was it live action or animated? was it in english or another language?

Answer (score 5):

Must be [*American Cyborg: Steel Warrior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Cyborg:_Steel_Warrior)

> After World War III people are sterile and ruled by the artificial
> intelligences they created in this violent world. The only woman who
> was able to give life to a fetus has to take it through the dangerous
> city of Charleston, South Carolina to the port where a ship is on its
> way to Europe. She is followed by an android assassin through all the
> dangers, and only one man tries to help her survive and protect her
> from the killing machine.

"the baby"

[image]

"robot is hanging from his arm, and cuts it off"

[image]

[image]

"ripped-off arm of the robot"

[image]